how to adjust a plane that blocks light to let some light through
I have a plane that I use to block out light. However, now I would like it to let some light through. Is that possible to do?

You can use light portals https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/light_settings.html#area-lights

I'm using an environment map
